# Dynamic Filtering with dplyr in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am trying to select have the user select a column to show data that they would like to see. Then from there I am filtering it by which factor from the variable they would like to see the data for.  How can I get it to filter correctly?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(

    dashboardHeader(title  = "Diamond"),
    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardBody(
        column(2, wellPanel( selectInput("GroupLevel", "Variable",
                                         choices = c("Diamond Cut","Visible Color","Clarity Type"),
                                         selected = "Diamond Cut"),uiOutput("ui"))), 
        dataTableOutput("value")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    grouping <- list("Diamond Cut" = "cut",
                     "Visible Color" = "color", 
                     "Clarity Type" = "clarity")
    output$ui <- renderUI({
        if (is.null(input$GroupLevel))
            return()
        switch(input$GroupLevel,
               "Diamond Cut" = selectInput("dynamic", "Cut",
                                      choices = sort(unique(diamonds$cut))),
               "Visible Color" = selectInput("dynamic", "Color",
                                      choices = sort(unique(diamonds$color))),
               "Clarity Type" =  selectInput("dynamic", "Clarity",
                                       choices = sort(unique(diamonds$clarity)))
        )
    })

    data_table <-reactive(diamonds %>% 
                              group_by_(grouping[[{input$GroupLevel}]]) %>% 
                              summarise_if(is.numeric,mean) %>% 
                              dplyr::filter(grouping[[{input$GroupLevel}]] == {input$dynamic}))
    output$value <- renderDataTable({data_table()},options = list(searching = FALSE, paging = FALSE))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try with filter_(), which will evaluate character expressions.

Comment: @BrunoPinheiro I have, it still doesn't filter correctly

Comment: Put the filter before the summarize.  Why are you grouping if you are only showing on level?

Comment: @Elin Putting the filter before year didn't work. In the actual data set I am grouping by a couple other variables like `Week` and `Year`.

Comment: Before year?   You should definitely subset first, then summarize. You can make the filtering as complex as you want.   Your piped analysis is pretty non standard. Why are you repeating the same list of values and labels multiple times?